# Como posso executar uma classe (constrói um JFrame com navegador) por meio de um actionPerformed de um botão?

Tags: java

Estou construindo uma aplicação em java que possui um navegador construído por meio de uma classe java.

Quero saber como posso chamar essa classe (classe executável) por meio de um actionPerformed de um JButton, ou seja, quando clicar em um botão quero que o navegador seja construído pela classe e inicializado.

Sem a chamada do botão o navegador funciona perfeitamente, então só preciso saber como chamá-lo por um JButton.

Segue classe construtora do navegador:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;

public class YoutubeViewer{
    public static String url;

    public YoutubeViewer(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeInterface.open();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reprodução de Áudio/Vídeo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        NativeInterface.runEventPump();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NativeInterface.close();
            }
        }));
    }

    public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/v/UWz_Sqj-mvI";
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        webBrowser.navigate(url);
        return webBrowserPanel;
    }
}
```

Tenho um botão já feito e preciso chamar a classe acima por meio de um actionPerformed. Qual o código que utilizo para realizar isso?

Segue actionPerformed do JButton:

```
private void btnNavegadorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    /* 
       Call browser
       Code here
    */
}
```

Comment: Você quer abrir um executável passando parametros via java?

Comment: Quero abrir a classe acima, por meio de um botão

Comment: Comece inicializando a tela dentro do construtor e remova esse main ai. O main só deve existir na classe principal da aplicação.

Comment: então devo instanciar a classe no actionPerformed do botão?

Comment: Não foi bem isso que eu disse, vou tentar responder, apesar da pergunta não ter um código executável.

Comment: tenho q colocar o código que constrói o frame e a função que retorna o browser dentro do construtor?

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo, foi o que deu pra responder com as informações passadas.

Answer (score 1):

Sua tela está sendo construída no main, a não ser que seja extremamente necessário isso, delegue a construção para seu construtor, removendo tudo do main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;

public class YoutubeViewer{

    public String url;

    public YoutubeViewer(String url) {
        this.url = url;

        NativeInterface.open();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reprodução de Áudio/Vídeo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        NativeInterface.runEventPump();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NativeInterface.close();
            }
        }));
    }   

    public JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
         //url = "https://www.youtube.com/v/UWz_Sqj-mvI";
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        webBrowser.navigate(url);
        return webBrowserPanel;
    }
}
```

E depois no botão:

```
private void btnNavegadorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    YoutubeViewer ytv = new YoutubeViewer("link a ser aberto");
}
```

Repare que o método `getBrowserPanel` não precisa mais ser estático se você delegar ao construtor a criação da tela. E a linha `url = "https://www.youtube.com/v/UWz_Sqj-mvI";` precisa ser removida senão a url passada como parâmetro jamais será carregada.

Comment: Agora, ele está instanciando normalmente, pois até a janela é iniciada pelo sistema, mas não é possível ver a janela e nem a aplicação é iniciada. Aparece o seguinte erro: "Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/openide/loaders/DataObject"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-openide-dataobjectdnd; mask=4; class=org.openide.loaders.DataObject
"

Comment: @ViniciusViana então é necessário que você forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar.

Comment: Tenho a seguinte situação: tenho um Jframe que inicia a aplicação e dentro do Jframe tenho um botão que chama a classe construtora do navegador inicializando ela com a url passada como parámetro. Então preciso saber como inicializar a classe com o parâmetro passado.

Comment: @ViniciusViana eu li a pergunta, mas como disse, não basta apenas explicar por texto, é preciso demonstrar o problema através de um ***exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*** (leia o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que eu e outras pessoas dispostas a te ajudar possam simular o problema.